# Java: Reading lines of text from MappedByteBuffers

Tags: java, file-io

I have a relatively largish (262 Mb) data file that I'm reading via a mappedByteBuffer. The majority of this file is binary data but there are portions of the data file that are in plain text. I'd like to be able to print out the lines of text and store the binary data. The file has a fixed format so I know what portions are supposed to be binary and which are plain text.

Right now I'm reading individual bytes of the text section, storing it in a character array until I hit a linebreak and printing the text. It works but it feels strongly like I'm doing something wrong; creating a homebrew solution to functionality that already exists somewhere. Is there a better solution for reading both lines of text and binary data from the same file? The only other solution I can think of is switching back and forth between BufferedReader and my MappedByteBuffer, storing my place in the file, but that feels even more wrong.

Comment: If you know the exact format then why not for the first parse, parses the lines of text and the binary part into separate files. Then you can apply whichever parser base on how you stored the parts?

Comment: The text is interspersed among the binary data. That seams like it would be very easy to mess up. Also, the text indicates the size of the binary portions. I'd prefer to keep binary portions separated to avoid losing my place.

Comment: If this is an open-standard format then you would expect someone already written the tool. If its not then you would have to write the parser yourself. You could try adopt the SAX parser events driven framework. Either ways, you would have to parse this file manually.

Comment: Usually such a file format would store the length of the text part (or generally any variable length part) somewhere, so that you could do that efficiently. The biggest flaw here is reading until you hit a linebreak. If the format offers no alternative, then it wasn't designed very well.

Comment: It wasn't designed particularly well but that is out of my control. There is a text header containing relevant data followed by the binary data. There's several thousand of these text/binary sections and both sections can be of variable length throughout the file. Also, all the binary data is in little endian and uses unsigned datatypes. I'm having all kinds of fun reading it.